# No permissions for owned folder

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, 22.04

Lubuntu 22.04. Inside my home folder I create a new directory and chown it to another user. But that user still doesn't have permissions to that folder.
I do literally the following:

```
> whoami
user1

> cd /home/user1/
> mkdir folder1
> sudo chown tech-user:tech-user /home/user1/folder1/
> ls -lah folder1/
drwxrwxr-x  2 tech-user tech-user 4,0K июн 12 11:23 .

> sudo -u tech-user touch /home/user1/folder1/1
touch: cannot touch '/home/user1/folder1/1': Permission denied
```

Comment: `tech-user` has no permission for `/home/user1`

Comment: should it? it has permissions to `/home/user1/folder1`

Comment: It looks like the desired user (`tech-user`) must have execution permissions for all the directories from the `/` down to the desired directory. So I've added `chmod o+x ~` and now I `tech-user` can write to `folder1`